# How do I define 'scss' to the project I created with 'rollup'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, frontend, rollup

I will create a React ui library. I decided to use 'rollup' for this. I will write the project with typescript and I want to use scss. How do I define scss to the project?

[The structure I use is in this link.](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/rollup-typescript-react-starter)

The structure I use is in this link. How do I define scss based on this structure?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [rollup-plugin-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-sass) and do the necessary changes in the *rollup.config.js*

Comment: thanks, the answer came.
https://github.com/saltyshiomix/rollup-typescript-react-starter/issues/1